# Search Sqlite Database using PHP and HTML input

Tags: php, ajax, sqlite

**EDIT - CODE BELOW SHOWS CORRECTIONS**

I need to create a search function that will search a SQLite database for a certain date range.

For example:

- if the user were to input "7", it would look for all records that have a date within the next 7 days.
- If the user were to input "-7" it would look for all records in the last 7 days.

So far I have:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * from table where record_date between date('now') and date('now', :record_date||' days')"; 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':record_date' , '%'.$webdata['record_date'].'%', SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) { 
        echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($row['id'])  . " : " . 
        htmlspecialchars($row['record_date']).'</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

This doesn't seem to bring through any results.

If I use [SqliteOnline.com](https://sqliteonline.com/) to query the database this does work fine with the query:

```
SELECT * from table where record_date between date('now') and date('now', '7 days')
```

Comment: There's a syntax error there. Too much red code, so most likely a missing closing quote somewhere

Comment: As @Don'tPanic said, you have a syntax error at the very least. The line that starts with `$sql="SELECT * from` doesn't have the closing double quote for starters.

Comment: My original code contains the closing quote. It was a typo, now corrected in the question. Still getting no result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named placeholders shouldn't be quoted as they are then interpreted as a literal value.

Try changing:

```
date('now', ':record_date days')
```

to:

```
date('now', :record_date||' days')
```

---

You also need to modify the following from:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':record_date' , '%'.$webdata['record_date'].'%', SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

to:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':record_date' , $webdata['record_date'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

Comment: This works fine as a query and brings through results. However it doesn't bring through any results with my search functions.

Answer (score 0):

Close the quotes
$sql="SELECT * from table where record_date between date('now') and date('now', ':record_date days');"

Comment: My original code contains the closing quote. It was a typo, now corrected in the question. Still getting no result..